# How can I skip an async task that is already running?

Tags: ansible

I would like to create an Ansible playbook with an `async` task followed by an `async_status` task that lets me do the following:

1. I run the playbook on my laptop. It starts the async task in the background and starts polling it with the async_status task.
2. I reboot my laptop. The async task continues running on the server.
3. I run the playbook again. It recognizes that the async task is already running on the server and goes straight to the async_status task, polling the task that was started in step 1.

Does Ansible support this? How can I create a playbook that does it?

Comment: Nice problem. It's possible to create such a framework. Put it on https://serverfault.com/ . Some might argue it is not a [SW problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is rather [about automating admin tools](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I moved the question to ServerFault [How can I skip an async task that is already running?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1126724/how-can-i-skip-an-async-task-that-is-already-running/1126725#1126725).